# Get json values for each level using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use a recursive function to get the last key value form a simple `json` using `javascript`

I have this `json`:

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': 12,
      'd': 'Hello World'
    },
    'e': [1,2,3]
  }
}
```

And my expected result is:

```
{
  'a/b/c': 12,
  'a/b/d': 'Hello World',
  'a/e': [1,2,3]
}
```

I'm trying with:

```
function getDeepKeys(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
            keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function (subkey) {
                return key + "/" + subkey;
            }));
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

But for some reason, it returns me:

`a/b/c/d/e/0/1/`, I'm not sure why it is adding those numbers there.
Someone has an idea about how I can do it?

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing the if conditional to `if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[key]))`.

Comment: Seems like we need to prevent the code from descending into arrays. But I am not 100% sure that this will cover all possible cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `Object.keys` to loop the keys of the objects and with recursion, you can go deeper through the nested objects.

```js
let obj = {'a': {'b': {'c': 12,'d': 'Hello World'},'e': [1,2,3]}},
    result = Object.create(null),
    loop = function (o, arr, result) {
      Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
        arr.push(k);
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(o[k])) loop(o[k], arr, result);
        else result[arr.join('/')] = o[k];        
        arr.splice(-1);
      });
    };    
    
loop(obj, [], result);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why create an object that doesn't inherit from `Object` here. It seems that this would lead to unexpected behavior? For example, you should be able to call `result.hasOwnProperty()`, but you can't if you neuter it with `Object.create(null)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I’m creating an object that way because I know this approach only needs an object with specific keys, so the call of `.hasOenProperty()` is not a problem.

Comment: I was really interested in whether there was *a benefit* of doing this that outweighs ending up with an object that doesn't have the behavior of a standard object.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it iteratively with an explicit stack which has less overhead than recursion and won't blow the call stack:

```js
const pathify = o => {
  const paths = {};
  const stack = [[o, []]];
  
  while (stack.length) {
    const [curr, path] = stack.pop();
    
    for (const k in curr) {
      if (typeof curr[k] === "object" && !Array.isArray(curr[k])) {
        stack.push([curr[k], path.concat(k)]);
      }
      else {
        paths[`${path.join("/")}/${k}`] = curr[k];
      }
    }
  }
  
  return paths;
};

console.log(pathify({'a':{'b':{'c':12,'d':'Hello World'},'e':[1,2,3]}}));
```

Comment: That's a nice (and fast) way to do it (although it would have to be a pretty big object to blow the call stack).

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be making it more complicated than necessary. You can test for an array with `Array.isArray` and an non-object (`typeof !== 'object`) and just return the path and value. Otherwise recurse for each entry. `reduce()` is good for that. Passing the current path as an argument to the recursive function is convenient too:

```js
let obj = {'a': {'b': {'c': 12,'d': 'Hello World'},'e': [1,2,3]}}

function getValues(obj, path = []){
    return (Array.isArray(obj) || typeof obj !== 'object')
    ? {[path.join('/')]: obj}
    : Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => 
        Object.assign(acc, getValues(val, path.concat(key)) )
    , {})
    }
    

console.log(getValues(obj))
```